# Mysql trigger with cursor to fetch all column from one table and insert into other

Tags: mysql

I have two table product and product_log. When i insert,update or delete a record in product table i want to call a trigger which perform following operations

```
1:- fetch all column name from product table.
2:- arrange product table column name and value in json format 
e.g. log = {"col_first":"value_first", "col_second":"value_second"}
3:- After that insert into product log.

product table 
    create table product(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(100),
    description text,
    created_at datetime 
    );

product_log table
   create table product_log(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    table_name varchar(100),
    logdata longtext,
    created_at datetime 
    );
```

Here is my trigger code which is not correct please help me friends. Any suggestion will be appreciated. thank You

```
DELIMITER $$
    create trigger after_product_insert
    AFTER INSERT on product for each ROW
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
        declare stProduct text;
        DECLARE stRes text;
        declare prodct cursor for SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='mydb' AND TABLE_NAME='product';

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

        OPEN prodct;
            stLoop: LOOP
                FETCH prodct INTO stProduct;
                IF finished = 1 THEN 
                    LEAVE stLoop;
                END IF;

                SET stRes = CONCAT(stProduct,",",stRes);
            END LOOP stLoop;
            insert into product_log(table_name, logdata) values ('product', stRes); 
        CLOSE prodct;

    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

After Query Run table look like:

```
Product table
|----------|----------|------------------|---------------------|
|   id     |   name   | description      |   created_at        |
|----------|----------|------------------|---------------------|
|    1     | laptop   | all about laptop | 2020-01-29 00:00:00 |
|----------|----------|------------------|---------------------|

product_log table
|----------|----------------|---------------------------------------------|---------------------|
|   id     |   table_name   |     logdata                                 |   created_at        |
|----------|----------------|---------------------------------------------|---------------------|
|    1     |   product      | {"name":"laptop","description":"all ..",..} | 2020-01-29 00:00:00 |
|----------|----------------|---------------------------------------------|---------------------|
```

Comment: If you ask a blind question, someone may give the whole code. But you are not getting equipped. Instead, you shall attempt your MySQL code, run the same and come back with outcome / errors so that the Answers will uplift you.

Comment: thank you @nnn for your suggestion i edit my question please check

Answer (score 0):

If you just concat, it can not be used as json.

```
json_set(columnname, key, value[, key, value]);
```

Secondly, if you just want pairs of values inside a longtext, you can use

```
select group_concat( concat(name, ":", description) SEPARATOR ",")...
```